# Generating patch consisting all commits from a historic branch, using only the branch name

Tags: git, git-branch, patch, branching-and-merging

We delete feature branches after merging them to the master.  On occasions we need to generate a patch consisting all commits from a historic branch that no longer exists.

To simplify the process, I'd like to provide a script that generates such patch, requiring only the historic branch name as the input.

(branch name can easily be obtained from the bug tracking system)

Answer (score 1):

Branches in git are simply a line of text in a file, pointing to a commit. When deleting a branch, there is no history of it out side the reflog. I would recommend tagging the end of your release branches right before merging them, this way you can browse the list of tags, which you can branch from when you need to create a patch from the previously  released code.

```
git tag -a 1.1 -m "Release 1.1"
git merge release/1.1
git branch -d release/1.1
```

Then you can list tags with `git tag` and later `git branch hotfix/1.2 1.1` to create a branch from the tag.

If you don't want to do this, you could use the following to list all merge commits in your history, which normally will include the branch name that was merged. You could then go to the second parent of the merge commit which will be the last commit of your release branch.

```
git log --oneline --merges --grep="<branch name>"
git show --pretty=raw <commitId>
git branch hotfix/1.1 <commitId>^2
```

You could combine these commands and obtain what you are asking for,  but as mentioned, I would strongly recommend using tags for this purpose.